# ResyRequest Delphi para fazer Get purchaseOrders na amazon

Tags: delphi, rest, amazon-aws, get, requisição

Boa tarde, estou me comunicando com a API da AWS, via postman está tudo correto, no delphi estou usando o componente TRestRequest, já consegui fazer o post do Token funcionar, agora estou levando o token para o get para retornar os pedidos, meu problema está em passar as configurações do Authorization type AWS Signature, pois estou criando o parâmetro no Request do delphi como Authorization e o conteúdo é o que está no postman mas depois percebi que esse conteúdo tem um valor dentro chamado Signeture que toda vez que é acionado o Get ele é alterado, minha duvida é se tem alguém que já conseguiu fazer o get no purchaseOrders da Amazon via delphi com Restrequest ou outro componente se puder compartilhar como devo colocar. vou deixar em baixo como estou montando os dados no delphi.

strToken := GerarToken; 'Gera o Token via Post que está funcionando'
DM_GLOBAL.RESTClient1.BaseURL   := 'https da amazon';
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Resource := 'Caminho do Get na url';

DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem; //Adds a new Parameter Item
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[0].name    := 'Authorization'; //sets the name of the parameter.
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[0].Value   := 'Valor do parâmetro que está no postman onde contem chave de login, data, local e o final é uma chave gerada em cada requisição';<-- local que devo concatenar os dados fixos que já tenho com a signature.
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[0].Kind    := pkHTTPHEADER; //Tipo do parâmetro
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[0].Options := [poDoNotEncode];

DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem; //Adds a new Parameter Item
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[1].name    := 'Accept'; //sets the name of the parameter.
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[1].Value   := 'application/json'; //Adds the value of the parameter, in this case, the XML data.
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[1].Kind    := pkHTTPHEADER;
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[1].Options := [poDoNotEncode];

DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem; //Adds a new Parameter Item
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[2].name    := 'x-amz-access-token'; //sets the name of the parameter.
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[2].Value   := strToken; //Adds the value of the parameter, in this case, the XML data.
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[2].Kind    := pkHTTPHEADER;
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Params.Items[2].Options := [poDoNotEncode];

DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Method   := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET; // Define o método
DM_GLOBAL.RESTRequest1.Execute;//faz a requisição
no final retorna 403 forbiden pois dentro do authorization o valor está correto até chegar o signature que não sei como gerar, dentro tem um campo sgnetureHeaders que parece que serve para dizer como é montada a Signature : 'SignedHeaders=accept;host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date' mas o campo host no postman diz que é automatico então não tenho acesso ao valor dele para poder gerar.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema que não dependa de nenhuma API e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Boa tarde, pessoal consegui, vou adicionar aqui o código que usei para conseguir a assinatura versão 4 da aws.
unit Unit1;

```
    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Hash, System.DateUtils, Data.Cloud.CloudAPI, REST.Types, REST.Client, Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope;

    type
      TByteArr = array of byte;
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Memo1: TMemo;
        Button1: TButton;
        RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
        RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
        RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
        function BytesToHexConverter(b: Tbytes): string;
        function ByteToString(const Value: TByteArr): String;
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      //VJSONObject: TJSONObject;
      strToken, strteste : String;
      passo1, passo1_hashed, passo2, passo31, key,
      method, service, host, region, endpoint, request_parameters,
      access_key, secret_key, amzdate, datestamp, canonical_uri,
      canonical_querystring, canonical_headers,
      signed_headers, payload_hash, canonical_request,
      algorithm, credential_scope, string_to_sign, signature,
      authorization_header, headers, request_url, accept, access_token   : String;
      kSecret, kDate, kRegion, kService, signing_key: TArray<Byte>;
    begin
      method := 'GET';
      service := 'execute-api';
      host := 'sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com';
      region := 'us-east-1';
      accept := 'application/json'; //;charset=UTF-8
      access_token := 'Atza|IwEBIMLzhGYPO2ncSOeNuPywr0Wdz0Ge0eCN3Ecf7H_VyHK4onSVPJ8uZ9f5rRrqLMmav32yWpqrOfelHTyG8vCxVEAS568W7q' + 'pYSewVZyIroDXFQ81zw_ryYcSzqQFGP_S7gUy1AAQ9ngb6gD-EAz5JdcZWcb5v5gOH5Wr_poKz2ZHqBVq-al2N5hs0VES9E5fmt2GT5Kvu6h4_2no2tT_i0aLpZRWEKaKy0gtel3pkWyh3an7oJUDwyN3Ov_GHBWbfh' + '7sTnAvOwprSkCDH4JR-H70D1plIogj8h9U-dWq3wB5rYECeaB6Sqxz2BSI9UtBF6a5wrCn5YsLLlw6GlksUSt-A';
      endpoint := 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com';
      request_parameters := ''; //'Action=DescribeRegions&Version=2013-10-15';

      access_key := 'AKIAQEK44BHSNVAJ6NM4';
      secret_key := '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';

      amzdate := '20221125T202258Z'; //'20221125T175626Z';
      datestamp := '20221125';

      canonical_uri := '/vendor/orders/v1/purchaseOrders';

      canonical_querystring := request_parameters;

      canonical_headers := 'accept:' + accept + #10 + 'host:' + host + #10 + 'x-amz-access-token:' + access_token + #10 + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + #10;

      signed_headers := 'accept;host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date';

      payload_hash := BytesToHexConverter ( THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(UTF8Encode('')));

      memo1.Lines.Add('payload_hash: ' + payload_hash);

      canonical_request := method + #10 + canonical_uri + #10 + canonical_querystring + #10 + canonical_headers + #10 + signed_headers + #10 + payload_hash;

      algorithm := 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
      credential_scope := datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request';
      string_to_sign := algorithm + #10 +  amzdate + #10 +  credential_scope + #10 + BytesToHexConverter(THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(UTF8Encode(canonical_request)));

      memo1.Lines.Add('BytesToHexConverter(THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(UTF8Encode(canonical_request))): ' + BytesToHexConverter(THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(UTF8Encode(canonical_request))));

      signature := BytesToHexConverter(THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(string_to_sign, signing_key));
      memo1.Lines.Add('signature: ' + signature);

      authorization_header := algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature;

      headers := '{"x-amz-date":' + amzdate + ',' + '"Authorization":' + authorization_header + '}';

      request_url := endpoint; // + '?' + canonical_querystring


      Memo1.Lines.Add('headers: ' + headers);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('request_url: ' + endpoint);


        RESTClient1.BaseURL := endpoint;
        RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('x-amz-date', amzdate,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
        RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('x-amz-access-token', access_token,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
        RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Authorization', authorization_header,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
        RESTRequest1.Accept := 'application/json';    //;charset=UTF-8
        RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET; // Define o método, aqui o post vai aditar se a chave já existir e inseir se não existir
        RESTRequest1.Resource := canonical_uri;

        try
          RESTRequest1.ClearBody;  // Adicona ao Body a string do JSON
          RESTRequest1.Execute; // Exceuta o método

          if (RESTResponse1.StatusCode = 200) then    //Status 200
          begin
            memo1.Lines.Add('200: ' + RESTResponse1.Content);
          end
          else
          begin
            memo1.Lines.Add('Error: ' + RESTResponse1.Content);
          end;
        finally
          RESTRequest1.ClearBody; // Limpo o Body para o próximo add
        end;
    end;

    function TForm1.BytesToHexConverter(b: Tbytes): string;
    var
     I        : Integer;
     s        : String;
    begin
     s:='';
     for i  := 0 to length(b)-1 do
       begin
        s:=s+b[i].ToHexString;
       end;
     s:= LowerCase(s);
     result:=s;
    end;

    function TForm1.ByteToString(const Value: TByteArr): String;
    var
        I: integer;
        S : String;
        Letra: char;
    begin
        S := '';
        for I := Length(Value)-1 Downto 0 do
        begin
            letra := Chr(Value[I] + 48);
            S := letra + S;
        end;
        Result := S;
    end;

    end.
```

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia, fiz a assinatura de um jeito manual, primeiro segui os passos em https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html para gerar a assinatura da mesma forma que o exemplo, e depois de ter trago o mesmo resultado fui agora adaptando os valores para usar de acordo com a api vendor me baseando também nesse link: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/connecting-to-the-selling-partner-api#step-3-add-headers-to-the-uri. Estou agora com um problema de retorno 403 no get que a amazon diz que pode ser a assinatura, creio que o corpo que eu estou passando esteja com alguma coisa errada, estou montando os headers com base no headers que o postman mostra, vou deixar aqui o código que estou usando, se alguém souber qual informação estou passando errado agradeço muito.

passo1 := 'GET'#10 +
'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/vendor/orders/v1/purchaseOrders'#10 +
'accept:application/json'#10+
'host:sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com'#10 +
'x-amz-access-token=' + 'Meu Token gerado'+ #10 +
'x-amz-date:' + FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDD',date) + 'T' + FormatDateTime('HHNNSS',IncHour(now,3)) + 'Z' + #10 +
#10 +
'accept;host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date'#10 +
BytesToHexConverter ( THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(UTF8Encode('')));
passo1_hashed := BytesToHexConverter(THashSHA2.GetHashBytes(UTF8Encode(passo1)));

passo2 := 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'#10 +
FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDD',date) + 'T' + FormatDateTime('HHNNSS',IncHour(now,3)) + 'Z' + #10 +
'20221125/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request'#10 +
passo1_hashed;

key := 'minha secret Key';
kSecret  := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('AWS4' + key);
kDate    := THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes('20221125', kSecret, SHA256);
kRegion  := THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes('us-east-1', kDate);
kService := THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes('execute-api', kRegion);
kSigning := THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes('aws4_request', kService);

strSignature := BytesToHexConverter(THashSHA2.GetHMACAsBytes(passo2, kSigning));

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).